# Reactjs: How to render the object n times?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my code:

```
 const [data, setData] = useState([
    {id: 1, name: 'paper', qty: 1},
    {id: 2, name: 'bottle', qty: 2},
 ]);
```

How can I render the object name n times by the `qty` value and display on some tags like `<h1>`.

For example:

```
paper
bottle
bottle
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example of your attempt, and include an example expected output. Example: "<h1>{name}{name}{name}</h1>" or "<h1>{name}</h1><h1>{name}</h1><h1>{name}</h1>" or something else entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([
    { id: 1, name: "paper", qty: 10 },
    { id: 2, name: "bottle", qty: 5 }
  ]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.map(({ name, qty }) => (
        <div>{new Array(qty).fill(<h1>{name}</h1>)}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```